# How do you get a web hosted pdf form to submit?

Tags: forms, pdf

I have a PDF form, that, on my desktop will submit the form data to a php file for processing.
However, the moment I move that form to the web host, it won't submit the data.

I've tried two public webservers as well as localhost/wamp with no luck. Like I said, if you open the file from the desktop, it submits the data just fine. 
I'm using Adobe Pro 9. I've tried FDF as well as HTML.

Any bright ideas out there?

Comment: I'm not au fait with PDF forms, but: If you access it on the web, are you downloading it and running it in Adobe Reader, or are you running it in a Reader plugin in your browser? What happens when you try to submit the form in the way you're doing it? Have you tried another browser/machine?

Comment: It's opening in the browser with... I assume... a default plugin. I've tried a couple different machines. if you open the pdf from your desktop with adobe reader and submit the form... it sends data to that path where I have a php set to receive and parse the data. That works... but... when you ftp the pdf to the webhost... you can open the document and fill the fields... but when you hit the submit button... no data is received by the processing file.